# Schedule Android Background Operations

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am trying to execute a background process on my android app every day at around 09h10 am. This works fine, but problem is after the first alarm has been fired at 09h10 am, it gets re-fired after 10 - 20 minutes throughout the day. I just want it to fire once a day, and only at that specified time. My code that sets the alarm manager is below:

```
PendingIntent reviewsPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,new Intent(this,ReviewReceiver.class),0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));

Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));

long interval = 6000*1440;

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(),interval,reviewsPendingIntent);
```

I have set the interval to `8640000` which is a day(I believe) if not, please advise accordingly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
PendingIntent reviewsPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,new Intent(this,ReviewReceiver.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,reviewsPendingIntent);
```

FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT will prevent the alarm to be set multiple times
AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24

Answer (score 1):

1000ms*60s*60m*24h = 86400000 so You missed one 0

Answer (score 0):

If you keep having some delay, it's because the sleep function is not precise. It's *around* the time you have set. Try with setExact and reschedule every day, doing the math by hand (initialTime + dayPassed * millsInADay) to have the best approximation.

If what Lindus has posted worked though, just forget it :) but I think that you'll have the same problem.

Comment: lol, dude that sounds so confusing... I get what you saying, but I can't imagine how I'll approach it

Comment: just call again alarm.setExact at the end of the Thread. If you don't care for some seconds of error, maybe the main problem is because of what Viktor has said.. :)